# How to remove the border around the image?

Tags: css, html

How to remove the border around the square?

How it looks:

[image: Screenshot of the undesired effect]

My HTML:

```
<input id="black" type="image" src="html5-canvas-drawing-app/images/color-swatch-brown.png" onClick="changeColorBlack()">
```

My CSS:

```
#black{
border:none;
outline:none;
background:none;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the image you are using? I tried reproducing this and didn't see a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disappear with it, set it's thickness to 0 instead:

```
border: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But what I meant is the white border around the square.(Black is the color of the background)

Comment: By using `border: none` you are setting the `border-style` of the object to `none`, but changing that don't necessarily imply the `border-width` will be 0. So in the end, well, you saw that happened.

Answer (score 3):

```
border: 0;
```

put in the My css file....

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reasons, stylesheets text/css are not very universally-predictable. Still, this should clear you all around:

```
img#black {
    border: 0px solid #00000;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Toss that in your style.css or whatever.  Not all of it may be necessary at the moment, but it will protect you from weird inheritance problems that may arise down the road.